# Android:PathPattern problematics with matching urls

Tags: android, regex, intentfilter

I know that this question came up several times, but until now there has been no solution.
Here's my problem.

I want to use a Intent-Filter to open my app then a specific URL is selected in an internet browser.

This specific URL looks like this:

http://host.example.com/name=blablabla&format=importantpart

So i want to check the format attribute after the second "=".

For that purpose i used the `android:pathpattern` attribute. Unfortunately android is using a simplified(useless) version of REGEX.

Here's what i tried so far:

```
<data android:pathPattern=".*\\=.*\\=importantpart"/>
```

notice that i try to escape the "=" with \\

I appreciate every commment :)

Comment: That does not look like a valid URL.

Comment: you're right. i corrected it.